# Powers of the Meijer G function

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to find the following integral:
$$
I = \int_0^{+\infty} J_{1}(2\beta\sqrt s) \Psi(m,1-m,\beta^2/a)^L d\beta,
$$
where $J_{1}(2\beta\sqrt s)$ is the known Bessel function, $\Psi$ is the tricomi function (which can be expressed in terms of hypergeometric functions), and $L$ is a positive integer.

I am trying to solve the problem using the Meijer G representation of both $J$ and $\Psi$ which is okay for $L =0, 1$. My questions are:

1) Is there a representation in terms of Meijer G for powers of the function $\Psi$ ?

2) In case I have a representation for the function $\Psi$ in terms of Meijer G, is there a representation for the powers of Meijer G ?

3) Any possibility of using the $H$-Fox function may be ?

Thank you

Comment: Try to work it out for $L=2$.